# Shipping mpiexec/mpirun along with static binary

Tags: mpi, binaryfiles, openmpi, mpich

I have a parallel code that uses MPI. The proper way to use this code is to compile from source on a PC/Cluster and then run as:

```
mpiexec -n X ./application -options
```

Unfortunately some people using this code are *nix challenged who find building from source a little daunting (dont ask why). These users only use the code on their own desktops/laptops.

For such users I simply compile a static binary (on an old enough OS with an old enough glibc that it runs on most PCs running Linux). The user can then run the code as follows:

```
./application -options
```

So now my question is that how can I ship mpiexec/mpirun along with my static binary so that a user can do something like:

```
./mpiexec -n 2 ./application -options
```

This way they can also take advantage of multiple cores on their desktops. Until now I have been telling them to do the right thing i.e., install MPI and compile my code from source.

By doing some testing I have found that if I compile hydra and ship `mpiexec.hydra` along with  `hydra_pmi_proxy` then I can run the code as follows:

```
./mpiexec.hydra -n 2 ./application -options
```

But I am not sure if this is the right approach? Will this cause any issues? I am thinking of doing the same thing for a Windoze binary (running in Cygwin).

The other option is a VBox image with everything pre-built but then downloading a large file becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Hydra, I'm going to assume you're using MPICH or something based on it.

The problem with only shipping a small portion of the full installation is that functionality will likely be missing.  You can make an assumption that the users who are unwilling to set up MPI themselves will only use certain functionality, and if they need more simply tell them to install it correctly.

There is an even more concerning situation to consider though.  If they already have MPI installed, and it's not the one you're shipping, you'll need to make certain that yours is the one found first.  In Windows, just put your binaries and libraries in the same folder, and Windows will find them first.  Linux is a little trickier, but you can manipulate PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to get yours first.  Another option is to wrap the mpirun call in a script.  This makes it easier to get the paths set up how you want them, and more advanced users can simply ignore it.